# Can I obfuscate CSS class names in Django?

Tags: django, compression, obfuscation, django-compressor, uglifier

I'm currently using "Django Compressor" to compress HTML, JS, and CSS files. 
These are the filters I use

```
COMPRESS_FILTERS = {
    'css': ['compressor.filters.yuglify.YUglifyCSSFilter'],
    'js': ['compressor.filters.yuglify.YUglifyJSFilter']
}
```

I really like the way it obfuscates my variables in js files. I don't know is it possible to obfuscate class names in CSS files too?

Answer (score 0):

[This website](http://cssobfuscator.com) can obfuscate css.

The downside is the file size increases.
If you want to obfuscate CSS, the file size will increase. Probably, it is the only way